# Importing data from, to and between sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a cell in sheet 1 (temperature value) and in order to get its corresponding kinematic viscosity value in another cell in sheet 1, I have to choose from a range of cells (in tabular format) in sheet 2.

What is the shortest formula or expression to import the right value of kinematic viscosity from sheet 2 into sheet 1?

Comment: Next time please DON'T WRITE IN ALL CAPS, because that's considered quite rude. Thank you. (To those who flagged this post: It's fairly trivial to edit it, though…)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data, or how you need to choose from the range of cells?  This will be critical for providing an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

try `vlookup` function.

```
=vlookup(look up value,range to lookup,value index)
```